# Symbols not found in OpenModelica compile

Tags: clang, osx-snow-leopard, linker-errors, openmodelica

I have hit a roadblock when trying to compile the current SVN trunk of OpenModelica on Mac OS X 10.8.5 without using ports, but rather using what is supplied with fink.

I have successfully installed all the prerequisites mentioned in the README.Linux.txt file. ./configure runs fine and produces working Makefiles. However, the compile of the omc binary is failing on this command:

```
gcc -I/sw/include -o omc *.o ../../Parser/libomparse_rml.a ../../Parser/libantlr3.a ../runtime/runtime.a -lModelicaExternalC -lOpenModelicaRuntimeC ../modpar/libmodpar.a -L/sw/lib -lm -L/usr/local/lib/plain -lrml  -L/usr/local/lib -lmico2.3.13   -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lm  -lpthread -llpsolve55 -lcolamd  -L../../build/lib/omc -Wl,-rpath,'@loader_path/../lib/omc'  -lgc -lexpat -L/sw/lib  -lintl  -llapack -lblas -liconv -lgc -lpthread -lm -ldl -lstdc++ -lfmi -lOpenModelicaFMIRuntimeC -lstdc++
```

The error is

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_jmi_log_node", referenced from:
     _jmi_global_log in libModelicaExternalC.a(libModelicaExternalC_la-jmi_global.o)
     _jmi_assert_failed in libModelicaExternalC.a(libModelicaExternalC_la-jmi_global.o)
 "_rml_prim_equal", referenced from:
     _Absyn__expEqual_5flabel7060 in Absyn.o
     _Absyn__onlyLiteralsInExp_5fExitCall_5ftraverseExpFunctionArgs_5fSC271 in Absyn.o
     _ConnectionGraph__merge_5flabel4327 in ConnectionGraph.o
     _DAEUtil__addDaeFunction_5fExitCall_5fUtil_5f_5fgetOption_5fSC23 in DAEUtil.o
     _Expression__expEqualWork_5fNextCase_5fFC268 in Expression.o
     _Expression__expEqualWork_5fNextCase_5fFC267 in Expression.o
     _Expression__expEqualWork_5fNextCase_5fFC263 in Expression.o
     ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried to find these symbols in the prerequisites, and it appears that rml_prim_equal is supposed to be provided by rmllib, but mine doesn't have it. I have located a file that provides this function [here](https://openmodelica.org/svn/OpenModelica/tags/TAG_MATHCORE_MATHMODELICA_ABB_EDITION_2_1_5_TC1/Compiler/VC7/rmlRuntime/runtime/common/p-equal.c) but I can't find this file in any of the current svn sources of openmodelica or mmc/rml.

I cannot determine where jmi_log_node is supposed to be coming from.

Can anyone shed any light on this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile without using RML and it will work (only bootstrapping is supported on OSX since new OSX releases broke old code).